# WAMP server doesnt work, no listening sockets avalible, unable to open logs

Tags: server, port

My WAMP server isn't working, when I hover over the orange W icon i get  "1 of two services running".

I did the right click on the icon, selected tools, selected test port 80
I got:

> ***** Test which uses port 80 *****
>
> ===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====
>
> 'find' is not recognized as internal or external command,
>      operable program or batch file.
>      Port 80 is not associated with TCP protocol
>      'find' is not recognized as internal or external command,
>      operable program or batch file.
>      Port 80 is not associated with TCP protocol
>
> ===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====
>
> Your port 80 is actually used by :
>
> Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16
>
> Press Enter to exit...

Then I tested port 3306 (that is supposed to be used by MySQL if Im not mistaken) in the same way as port 80.

I got:

> ***** Test which uses port 3306 *****
>
> ===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 3306 =====
>
> 'find' is not recognized as internal or external command,
>      operable program or batch file.
>      Port 3306 is not associated with TCP protocol
>      'find' is not recognized as internal or external command,
>      operable program or batch file.
>      Port 3306 is not associated with TCP protocol
>
> Press Enter to exit...

I went on the internet in search of a solution, none helped so far. I found some helpfull advice on stackoverflow so I did the folowing few things:

Run cmd in administrator mode.
Went to:

> C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin

and run:

> httpd.exe -e debug

At the end of the output I got:

> H01575: loaded module php5_module from C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/php5apache2_4.dll
>      (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket adress (protocol/network adress/port) is normally permitted. AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to adress [ : : ]:80
>      (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket adress (protocol/network adress/port) is normally permitted. AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to adress 0.0.0.0:80
>
> AH00451: no listening socket avalible, shutting down
>
> AH00015: Unable to open logs

Than I run resmon.exe in Start menu. There I saw that port 80 is used by httpd.exe. When I canged the port of the server to 8080, port 80 (in resmon view) disappeared and 8080 was taken over by httpd.exe. The above output also changed accordingly.  Port 3306 was nowhere to be seen.

Iam confused. Is port 80 taken or not? Im geting mixed messages here. Any help would be greatly appreciated or at least a point of direction where to look.

Maybe I should also add that because of this persistant problem I reinstalled my WAMP server. Did not help. Running WAMP as an admin didnt help as well and I do not have Skype on my desktop.

Comment: The "Port 80/3306 is not associated..." messages are probably bogus seeing that they are surrounded by error messages about missing commands ("find").

Comment: It looks like `MySQL` isn't running. Try starting it as a service. If after starting it, it still won't appear on port 3306, configure it to listen on port 3306. Apache is already running as a service, that's why it failed to bind to port 80 when you attempted to manually start another instance.

Answer (score 7):

Slana,

I think I had a similar problem with Wamp server in the past. Even though I kept changing localhost port number to 80, 8080, and etc. it did not work. So, this is what I did:

- Clicked on the Wamp Server icon.
- Apache -> Service -> Remove Service
- MySQL -> Service -> Remove Service
- Then reinstall both Apache and MySQL service.
- Restart the Wamp Server.

Sorry, I wish I could help you more.. I am a beginner in programming and still learning. I hope this helps with fixing the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Its appreciated. I did remove the services and than tried to reinstall them but nothing much had happened and I really wasnt in the mood to google for another hour or two on how to do that.

But I did fix the problem after all anyway being inspired by your advice.

I uninstalled the WAMP server completely. But this time after the uninstallation I went into safe mode and removed some remaining files that could not have been deleted in the normal run.

I then reinstalled WAMP and now it seems to be working fine. Hopefully it remains that way.

Comment: I am glad it's fixed for NOW... Hopefully it remains that way like you said.. and thanks for the comment! =)

Comment: I can't believe this worked! Anyone wondering, still works in 2019. After trying lots of other troubleshooting advice, this is what finally fixed it. Green icon once more. But, what I want to know is how did it get that way? Did the services get corrupted somehow? PS: In case it helps, I removed all references to wamp from my `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: thank you very much I did the same thing for mariaDB and it worked... I saw the green icon