# how to resolve this error on wamp?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, port

I am getting following when I test my port apache < port80:

```
***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====

Test for TCP
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 is not actually used.
```

I've tried many methods but it isn't working. `localhost` page isn't opening either. Wamp icon is kind of orange.

Comment: some software is occupying the port n°80 , may be skype !

Comment: 1st solution : change port, 
2nd solution : kill all process on port 80

Comment: yes , it happen because of the skype, any way go through this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753368/wamp-server-doesnt-work-no-listening-sockets-avalible-unable-to-open-logs

Comment: If you use skype, then skype is using port 80 by default. Then change the skype port no. If you haven't skype, then change your wamp port number.

Comment: It sounds to me like you do not actually have the TCP Stack running i.e. you have no network. Is this a laptop that is not currently connected to a network or the internet?

Comment: Or possibly WAMPServer is not running "as Administrator"

Comment: @bRIMOsBor I doubt that is the case. If something was using port 80 it would tell you what it was that was using 80, or at least the message would be different to the one quoted

Comment: @FaranAli I doubt changing ports would help as it looks like TCP itself is missing. Therefore option 2 would also be usless

Comment: @RiggsFolly You can follow this answer, NO need to change any thing    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705005/how-to-solve-wamp-and-skype-conflict-on-windows-7

Comment: @FaranAli But it has nothing to do with SKYPE. I dont think he has the TCP stack loaded. If SKYPE had port 80 locked, the WAMPServer message ___Would say that___

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're right, may be 80 is configured to receive only UDP sockets

Comment: @FaranAli Most likely a laptop that does not load the TCP stack if there is no active connection to the internet. Or possibly a completely naffed PC

Comment: If you dont have the TCP stack loaded because you have not installed the network drivers or you laptop does not load them because you are not connected to a network or the internet you will get this kind of error

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem, i turned off the W3SVC service and all applications associated with port 80, but Apache server still was offline. click on the wamp server tray, navigate to Apache->Service administration, and select "install service", the firewall rules for Apache should be created, restart all services, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

There might be an error in "httpd.conf" syntax. Right click on wamp icon, tools->check httpd.conf syntax and fix any errors.

Comment: This could have been a comment!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by closing all applications that were accessing port 80, stopping the all wamp services, closing it and restarting it using the run as administrator option.